# Changing Chrome/Firefox Proxy Settings from a Facebook Application

Tags: facebook, firefox, google-chrome, proxy

I was wondering if it was possible to change chrome or firefox's proxy settings from a facebook application, with the users consent. And if so, any ideas on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't possible. You'll need to provide a tutorial for your users how to do so (or work around the issue on your side), but web sites don't have access (and shouldn't have access) to those kinds of settings.

Comment: i thought that would be the case, would it be possible to interface with browser extensions like foxy proxy, or proxy switchy?

Comment: Maybe, but I wouldn't recommend it. If you absolutely need your users to change their proxy settings, you're going to lose a lot of users.

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and say that's WAY against the [Facebook Platform TOS](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/), specifically, section I, part 1.